# Switching limits.

Tags: integration

My problem is this, I want to change which limit goes first.

$$
  \int_{0}^{1} \int_{2y}^{2} e^{x^2} \,dxdy
$$

This integral, (which you guys already know is unnecessary hard otherwise) need to change the order of limits.

Eventually, I come to the conclusion (with a little help of the answer) that the new limits should look like

$0\le x\le2$ and $0\le y\le x/2$

But this does not come to me naturally and I always struggle to rewrite limits. Do you guys have any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: yes your new bounds are correct. In general, a rough sketch should help.

Comment: You have two $\int$ but only one $d$?!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of two coordinates, you may draw the integration region $ (x,y) $ inside a diagram.

The region above is just a **triangle** with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(2,1)$ and $(2,0)$. You may see this, since $y$ runs from 0 to 1 (so the region is within a horizontal strip from $y=0$ to $y=1$) and for each fixed $y$, the region goes in $x$-direction from $2y$ (which is a line with slope 1/2 through the origin) to the vertical line $x=2$.

In order to find the conditions for integrating the other way out, you just ``read off the diagram''. At first, you look how far the triangle extends in $x$-direction (namely from 0 to 2, so $0 \le x \le 2$). And then, for each fixed $x$, you look which $y$ are inside the triangle (all from the $x$-axis, up to the line $x=2y \Leftrightarrow y = x/2$, which means $ 0 \le y \le x/2 $).

Sketching integration domains graphically can make your life a lot easier!